VS Code keybinding to search from the beginning of the file
How do I make a keybinding that works like Ctrl+F / Cmd+F, but it starts searching at the top of the file, rather than at the current cursor location? Is there a command for that?

I'm unclear on exactly what you want to do.  Do you want to reveal the first match in the document - optimally without moving the cursor?

Exactly, I want to reveal the first match. And I do expect the cursor to move, like Ctrl+F always moves the cursor when it finds a match.

a feature-request for move on type to have a "move to first match in resource" mode would be interesting. if you raise one, please add a link here.

I haven't found a built-in command to search from the beginning of the file, but you can easily do it by chaining the two commands "go to the top" and "find" using the runCommands command.
As this requires passing args to runCommands, we can't do this in the built-in keyboard shortcuts UI. Instead, run the command "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)", and then add the following entry to the array:
[
  ...,
  {
    "key": "ctrl+cmd+f",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": ["actions.find", "cursorTop"]
    }
  }
]

Note that we're running "actions.find" (the "Find" command) first, and then "cursorTop". The reason is that the "Find" command seeds its search string from the word at the cursor position, so if we run "cursorTop" first, it will instead seed whichever word happens to be the first in the file.
A drawback to this solution is that even if you cancel your search immediately, it won't go back to your original cursor position.

You have at least a couple of options.  Try this keybinding:
{
  "key": "alt+f",                // whatever keybinding you want 
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      "actions.find", 
      "editor.action.goToMatchFindAction"
    ]
  }
}

You'll see it preforms the find on the word or selection at the cursor and then opens a little input box at the top where you could type 1 and Enter to go to the first find match.
Or, a little simpler but requires an extension, Find and Transform (that I wrote).  Try this keybinding:
{
  "key": "alt+f",                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "reveal": "first",     // or "last" or "next"
    "postCommands": ["actions.find", "cancelSelection"]
  },
  // "when": "editorHasSelection"    // so this runs only if there is a selection
}

It will reveal the first find match.  The find will again be based on your selection or the word at the cursor.
The "cancelSelection" postCommand is there because normally the extension selects ALL the find matches, not just the first one.  Canceling the selections will result in only the first revealed match being selected.
The "actions.find" postCommand isn't really needed or used, but it is a convenience to show the Find Widget where you can easily go to the next or previous match.

I like your solution with the Find and Transform extension! There's two issues I haven't been able to figure out yet: (1) If I type into the find bar, it won't search quite from the top of the file, but only onward from the first match of whatever happened to be under the cursor initially. (2) If I press the shortcut with no word currently under the cursor, it either does nothing or goes to the last match in the file (of the previously-searched word).

@JoLiss For case (2) on an "empty word" - the above keybinding should create a find for   empty lines if on an empty line and do nothing if otherwise in an empty space - there was a bug that was preventing the proper empty line behaviour.

@JoLiss For case (1): If you type into the Find Widget, this extension cannot modify what vscode is going to do.  The extension only reveals the first find match if you use it to do the find.  In the keybinding the extension is doing the find.  It opens a Find Widget but that is only afer the reveal
